# In jQuery how to loop through characters in a string and force match correct characters in input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, match

I am trying to match characters in an input, but when they write the wrong character it doesn't let you put it in the input.  This is what I have so far.

Not sure what I am doing wrong in the non-matching area where I try to rebuild the string to put back in the input.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#input1').keyup(function() {
    var dInput = $('#input1').val().toLowerCase();
    var a;
    var b;
    var word = "word";
    var inputword;
    word = word.toLowerCase();
    for (var i = 0; i < dInput.length; i++) {
      a = dInput.charAt(i);
      b = word.charAt(i);
      if (a == b) {
        // alert("matches");
      } else {
        // alert("not matching");
        console.log(i);
        for (var j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
          inputword = inputword + inputword.charAt(j);
        }
        $('#input1').val(inputword);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input1"></input>
```

Comment: You need to initialize `inputword` to an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently not using inputword for anything other that to clear the field when wrong.

I think you mean this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#input1').on("input",function() {
    var dInput = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    var a;
    var b;
    var word = "word";
    word = word.toLowerCase();
    var inputword="";
    for (var i = 0; i < dInput.length; i++) {
      a = dInput.charAt(i);
      b = word.charAt(i);
      if (a == b) {
        inputword += a;
      } 
      $('#input1').val(inputword);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input1"></input>
```

Shorter version

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#input1').on("input", function() {
    const dInput = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    let word = "word";
    word = word.toLowerCase();
    let inputword = "";
    [...dInput].forEach((char, i) => {
      if (char === word.charAt(i)) inputword += char;
    })
    $('#input1').val(inputword);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input1"></input>
```